# Edit Emmet Auto Comment Closing Tag | VS Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, emmet

Is there a way for the following changes to the auto-complete a comment using Emmet in VS code:

**1.** Auto-add comment to a UL tag? Currently, it will do it of an #ID and .class

**2.** Is it possible to edit the auto comment to add End i.e.:

```
  <div class="hero"></div>
  <!-- /.hero -->

change to:

  <div class="hero"></div>
  <!-- /.End hero -->


Here's the code in the VS Code User Preferences:

  "emmet.preferences": {
    "filter.commentAfter\n": "<!-- /[#ID][.CLASS] -->"
  },
   "emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    // Enable XHTML dialect for HTML syntax
    // “html”: “xhtml”
    "html": {
      "filters": "html, c"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the text you want to the comment filter:

```
"emmet.preferences": {
  "filter.commentAfter": "\n<!-- /End [#ID][.CLASS] -->"
}
```

You will end up with:

```html
<div class="hi"></div>
<!-- /End .hi -->

<div id="hi"></div>
<!-- /End #hi -->
```

Note the `.` or `#` will be before the `class` or `id` in the comment - no way to change that.

If you don't want the `.` or `#` use this instead:

```
"filter.commentAfter": "\n<!-- /End [ID][CLASS] -->"
```

Also, the slash `/` before `END` is purely optional - it is just more text you added - you can remove that if you want.  And I moved the `\n` from where you had it in your question.

Comment: Is there a way to add the element to the comment, div, header, button etc, so it comments as: `<!-- /End Div #hi --> <!-- /End Header #hi -->`

Comment: @Sanjay It doesn't look like is supported, it is in `filter.commentAfter` at https://docs.emmet.io/customization/preferences/ but I can't get it to work in vscode...